# Apply one Direct2D effect chain to multiple rectangles

Tags: c++, direct2d

I adopted code which implements a simple image editor. It applies an effect chain to one rectangular region within an image. Now the desired enhancement is to apply that same effect chain with exactly the same parameters to multiple rectangular regions within the same image.

Is there a way to have one effect chain instance work on multiple rectangles? Or do I have to create duplicates of the effect chain, one for each rectangle? One effect chain seems more efficient.

I'm not knowledgeable in D2D and I don't intend to delve too deeply into it, just for this one-off solution. I'm looking for pointers in the right direction and perhaps the appropriate functions to use. My first naive attempt was to put the rectangles into the effect chain via `ID2D1Effect::SetInput(index, image)` while incrementing the index, but that didn't work at all. `image` instances were created by some complicated input bitmap shuffling and have the rectangles of interest baked into them somehow. The original code used `SetInput(0, image)` with just one `image` instance and it worked. Unfortunately, I can't share code here, both for legal and for practical reasons (too much, too spread out).

Comment: The index argument is the index of the input. Some effects have no input (like the Flood effect), others 1 input (like the Grayscale effect), others multiple inputs. But one effect works on a fixed predefined set (0..N) of input images. You should be able to reuse the effect instance in a loop (eg: CreateEffect, SetInput(s), DrawBitmap => SetInput(s), DrawBitmap => SetInput(s), DrawBitmap etc.)

Comment: Thanks, Simon. I couldn't get it to work with SetInput() or SetInputEffect(), because that created cycles in the effect chain. What I ended up doing is to pass the whole image rectangle to the first render pass (ID2D1DeviceContext::DrawImage(), initializing the clean image and applying the 1st effect) and then to pass the additional effect rectangles in the subsequent render passes (adding the remaining effects). It's working fine now.